# How to start/stop/restart the fabric nodes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am using https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.1/fabric-ca for my setup.

Is this way correct to start/stop/restart the fabric nodes:

- `docker-compose stop`
- remove setup and run
- `docker-compose start`

Or is there any other correct way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I made to stop and start the network

Stop the network: `docker-compose stop`

Before starting it again, remove setup from docker compose and change the container scripts.

For CA scripts: replace everything with `fabric-ca-server start`
For orderer, just have: `orderer`
For peer, just have: `peer node start`
You don't need the fabric-ca-tool container but if you are starting it, make sure you remove all channel and chaincode logic from main method of run script.

Start the network: `docker-compose start`

Answer (score 0):

```
docker stop <container-id>

docker start <container-id>
```